# What are the current ways to get_absolute_url for django-mptt?

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-mptt

I read other questions, but I didn't find anything useful for Django 3, they just don't work.

The link type is needed like this: post/categories/subcategories/**etc

I think an adequate answer will be useful for everyone.

Tell me how to do it for DetailView

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Заголовок'))
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('URL'), blank=True)
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['title']

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['parent', 'slug']
    verbose_name = _('Категория')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Категории')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('category/<slug:slug>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
class CategoryListView(ListView):
model = Category
template_name = 'modules/post/category_detail.html'
context_object_name = 'category'
queryset = Category.objects.all()

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [reverse urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

###### codebase/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('my_app.urls', namespace='my_app_namespace')),
]
```

###### codebase/my_app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('category/<int:my_var>', views.my_view, name='my_view_name'),
]
```

###### codebase/any_python_file.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
reverse('my_app_namespace:my_view_name', args=[my_var])
>>> 'https://...'
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. I understand this. I ask to do it for the category tree, i.e. for mptt models, which has nested categories.

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your need. Can you explain with more details by editing your post ?